# Can't access to a folder as administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

SCENARIO: Windows Server 2008

I am logged as `administrator`. When I try to access to the `Documents and Settings` folder, I get the error message as show in the image (point 1)

Well, i tried to check the permission on that folder, and suddenly i notice that **Administrator dont have nothing set** (i mean all the privileges was blank [not ticked]) so i try to edit and set those permission. When i clicked OK i got an error messages (as the point 1) that i cant access to the folder Documents and Settings.

When i back again to the security tab of this folder, **Administrator is disappear** as you can see in the point 2. Also the button ADD is not available to add a new user.

[image]

**So what i misunderstanding ? or what i need to do to access that folder ?**

*just a note: I am developer with good skill but with basic skill about system administrator so please be patient if i am posting a silly question :) .*

So i would like to know some help or tips for all the expert people on here.

Let me know if i need to post more information to help this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Advanced section of the security dialog, you should click on the Owner tab and take ownership of the folder as Administrator. This will let you change the permissions.

[image]

It might be helpful for you to know that in Vista/7/2008/2008R2 Documents and Settings is simply a junction link that points to c:\users. If you're developing Windows apps, I hope you know this so that your program behaves properly :)

Comment: really thanks or your help and info, it was usefull :)